# What is correct term for map with shaded country outlines?

Tags: cartography

Many world maps, especially old ones, often have shaded country outlines in a particular color. The saturation becomes weaker towards the inside of the country and is strongest at its borders. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

Is there a correct term for such a map style?

This style does not just appear in historical maps, but for example also in [this National Geographic map of Europe from 1962.](https://www.maps.com/europe-map-1962.html)

Comment: I think it's called an antique style political map.

Comment: You should follow the [Geography Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/115473/geography) proposal and post this as an example question there -- it's a perfect candidate for a geography SE, and the proposal could use a bit more support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cartography they are called "tint bands", or sometimes, a "verge".

In GIS software it's a "shapeburst fill" (QGIS) or "buffered gradient fill" (ArcGIS)